# flyway init oracle insufficient privileges

Tags: oracle, flyway

I am executing Flyway from a Maven build. I am experienced with using Flyway, but haven't used Oracle for a few years. When it tries to run the init goal, I am getting this error message:

```
    [INFO] --- flyway-maven-plugin:3.0:clean (prepare-schema-using-flyway) @ my-project ---
    [INFO] Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@my-oracle-host:1521:dev (Oracle 11.2)
    [INFO] Cleaned schema "MY_SCHEMA" (execution time 00:03.483s)
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- flyway-maven-plugin:3.0:init (prepare-schema-using-flyway) @ my-project ---
    [INFO] Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@my-oracle-host:1521:dev (Oracle 11.2)
    [INFO] Creating Metadata table: "MY_SCHEMA"."schema_version"
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 16.991s
    [INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 21 09:44:09 CDT 2014
    [INFO] Final Memory: 20M/160M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:3.0:init (prepare-schema-using-flyway) on project my-project: org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.FlywaySqlScriptException: Error executing statement at line 17: CREATE TABLE "MY_SCHEMA"."schema_version" (
    [ERROR] "version_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    [ERROR] "installed_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    [ERROR] "version" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    [ERROR] "description" VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    [ERROR] "type" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    [ERROR] "script" VARCHAR2(1000) NOT NULL,
    [ERROR] "checksum" INT,
    [ERROR] "installed_by" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    [ERROR] "installed_on" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    [ERROR] "execution_time" INT NOT NULL,
    [ERROR] "success" NUMBER(1) NOT NULL
    [ERROR] ): ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

When I tried to execute the same SQL through a JDBC Connection (I used DBHelper from IntelliJ) I got the same error message. When I removed all of the double quotes, it executed successfully.

I can't imaging that Flyway 3.0 isn't compatible with Oracle, but I suspect that there may be a server setting that specifies the character that surrounds database objects during creation. For example, "my_table"."my_id" or [my_table].[my_id]

Alternatively, is there a way to turn off the double quotes as part of Flyway's configuration?

Comment: The double-quotes are valid but might be affecting what you're doing. Is the actual value of `MY_SCHEMA` uppercase; or was the quoted value mixed or lower case perhaps? If mixed-case identifiers are quoted they have to exactly match all the time; so you should probably make all the values that are being automatically quoted uppercase in your script to avoid future pain.

Comment: The double quotes are always suspicious but I wonder if there's something else going on here.  If the schema name is wrong the error should be `ORA-01918: user 'MY_SCHEMA' does not exist`.  The `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges` implies the schema exists but you don't have permission to modify it.  Do you have multiple "MY_SCHEMA" users, with different capitalization, and different permissions?  Check `select * from dba_sys_privs where lower(grantee) = 'my_schema';`.

Comment: the user who connects by jdbc must have the privilege `create any table` , if it is not the same as MY_SCHEMA. If it doesn't, you will get the error you have shown. If MY_SCHEMA is the same user who connects by jdbc, then you have to possess the privilege `CREATE  TABLE`

Comment: @Tim Andersen, can you show the output of this `create table` statement when you run it using a SQL tool ? something like `sqlplus` would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

I do honestly believe that the "quotation" has nothing to do with the problem, even though it's really annoying and will always lead to issues consulting Oracle dictionary views without the proper use of functions as `lower`. The real key here is the error message: `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`.

It normally means:

- The user who connects by `JDBC` is not the same as `MY_SCHEMA`. If this is the case, the user must possess the privilege `CREATE ANY TABLE` or a role which such privilege ( like `DBA` ).
- The user who connects by `JDBC` is `MY_SCHEMA`. If this is the case, your user must possess the privilege `CREATE TABLE`, or a role which contains such system privilege ( like `RESOURCE` )

According to the GitHub project of `flyway`, one very similar issue was reported and solved by ensuring that the user has been granted the system privilege `CREATE VIEW`

> Ensure that the character set of the Oracle database supports Unicode.
> In addition, for the initial creation of the database, the Oracle user
> must have the **CREATE VIEW** system privilege. Without this privilege,
> the following error might be generated during installation: Schema
> creation failed: **ORA-01031: insufficient privileges.**

What I saw as well in your log message is that you are cleaning the schema before run the creation. If such operation implies dropping the `MY_SCHEMA` user, you should take care that such creation contains the necessary system privileges.

Also `flyway` recommends deal with schema creation outside, if privileges might be an issue.

> It's better for users to manually deal with schema creation if Flyway
> isn't able to do it correctly due to permissions. I suppose it's a
> trade off between convivence and security - applying permissions
> because you might one day need them feels wrong. In this case, you can
> apply the GRANTs you need.

If you have access to the database with enough privileges, my first recommendation to check whether is or not an issue with permissions is to do the operation with an Oracle user with the role DBA, therefore you will be able to verify that it works.

For your message I guess you are in a development environment, so it shouldn't be a problem.